# Exception ENonAIRException when installing custom package

Tags: delphi, exception, delphi-xe

I have a custom package (which is using FibPlus and IBExpress). Package builds ok, but when trying to install it it gives me this exception : Exception ENonAIRException. Does anyone know something about it? What it generates it?

LE: found http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/DesignEditors.EDesignPropertyError_Members - but it doesn't help

LE2: error is raised when installing the package, and the IDE is trying to load the package. bellow the madExcept report:

```
21ba0eb1 +0ad delphicoreide150.bpl PakList           896 +20 TPackageListItem.LoadDesignPackage
7c91e485 +009 ntdll.dll                                      KiUserExceptionDispatcher
7c92487a +048 ntdll.dll                                      RtlAppendUnicodeToString
207a8c49 +055 coreide150.bpl       PakLoad           217  +7 TPackage.Load
207ab419 +061 coreide150.bpl       PakMgr            591  +2 TDesignPackage.Load
21af8317 +05b delphicoreide150.bpl PasCppPakMgr     2253  +4 TIDEDesignPackage.Load
500a014a +04e rtl150.bpl           Classes          5284  +2 TStrings.IndexOf
21af7bbb +0ff delphicoreide150.bpl PasCppPakMgr     2059 +20 TProfileData.LoadIntersectingPackageGroups
21af81db +077 delphicoreide150.bpl PasCppPakMgr     2214  +8 TIDEDesignPackage.LoadRequiredDesignPackages
21af83ce +112 delphicoreide150.bpl PasCppPakMgr     2266 +17 TIDEDesignPackage.Load
5003a7c1 +01d rtl150.bpl           System          12170  +2 @AfterConstruction
21af812b +06b delphicoreide150.bpl PasCppPakMgr     2178 +11 TIDEDesignPackage.DelayLoad
21ba0f0c +030 delphicoreide150.bpl PakList           916  +3 TPackageListItem.LoadWait
21ba0e73 +06f delphicoreide150.bpl PakList           891 +15 TPackageListItem.LoadDesignPackage
21b9feeb +067 delphicoreide150.bpl PakList           559  +7 TPackageListItem.SetIsInstalled
21b9fcbb +0d3 delphicoreide150.bpl PakList           474 +13 TPackageList.AddPackage
21bacba0 +090 delphicoreide150.bpl BasePasProjOpts  1670  +8 TProjOptsManager.InstallPackage
21bade5f +003 delphicoreide150.bpl BasePasProjOpts  2363  +0 TProjectOptions.InstallPackage
21b8561d +191 delphicoreide150.bpl PasMgr          11722 +18 TPascalPackageCodeUpdater.InstallPackage
21b028ef +06f delphicoreide150.bpl PkgContainers     178  +8 TStdPackageProjectContainer.CommandHandler
2079350f +19f coreide150.bpl       ContainerIntf     866 +26 TIDEProjectManagerMenuObject.Execute
20795136 +176 coreide150.bpl       ContainerIntf    1114 +18 TProjectManagerMenuItem.Click
5029fc9b +013 vcl150.bpl           Menus            3390  +5 TMenu.DispatchCommand
502a0e7a +082 vcl150.bpl           Menus            4496  +4 TPopupList.WndProc
502a0dc9 +01d vcl150.bpl           Menus            4471  +2 TPopupList.MainWndProc
500afa64 +014 rtl150.bpl           Classes         13491  +8 StdWndProc
77d189e3 +00a USER32.dll                                     DispatchMessageW
50358af7 +0f3 vcl150.bpl           Forms            9760 +23 TApplication.ProcessMessage
50358b3a +00a vcl150.bpl           Forms            9790  +1 TApplication.HandleMessage
50358e65 +0c9 vcl150.bpl           Forms            9927 +26 TApplication.Run
```

Comment: Find the code that raises the exception and show it to us

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - If I could find from where it is raised, it would be simple :) Just installing the package and it raise this error...

Comment: Unless you can debug it, you probably need to strip out code bit by bit until the exception goes away. Concentrate on code that runs on module load. That's code in `initialization` sections. Or perhaps code in `Register` procedures.

Comment: FTR: According to *ToolsApi*, an exception that won't produce an 'A'utomated 'I'ncident 'R'eport.

Answer (score 1):

I am probably way off track here but here's a scenario that happened to me relating to something similar. I hope this helps.

I have a big project that, for some reason, I could no longer open up the project options or edit the build configurations. I too thought that an improperly installed component or package was the culprit.

I turned off the EurekaLog IDE integration, tried to open the project options, then saw a Delphi error message about a wrong platform. That got me playing with the 2 platforms available "Unknown Platform Win64" which is weird because this is a Win7 machine but Ok, I'll play, the other Platform was simply "Windows" (the activated platform).

I disabled the "Windows" Platform, now my project options open, I can edit the build configurations and my darn coreide150.bpl error that has been driving me crazy for weeks is finally gone.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth I struggled with this today (Delphi XE). As @DavidHeffernan said, it had to do with module loading. In my case a long-standing package I was trying to re-install after a change requiring **a call to a .DLL** gave this uninterpretable error message. When I re-wrote things so it didn't, all was well again.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of any future searchers:

As well as the previous suggestions, check where any "requires" packages are being built to. I had this issue with a third-party package and it turned out to be that it was building into its own folder structure, rather than the ide default location. Reasonable enough, except that the output folder for the packages was not in my system path, so the install failed with this error because the dependent bpl could not be found.